# How to retrieve data from multiple URLs using BeautifulSoup (Python is only returning the last line)?

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter

I'm in the process of building a code that will retrieve all of the review titles from an airline review website. I am using 5 different URLs because I want to compare the titles between 5 different airlines. However, my code is only listing the review titles for the last URL listed, which is for Alaska Airlines. I initially created a list with all of the URLs together but it had the exact same error with only showing results for Alaska Airlines.

My code:

```py
# Insert the following command into the command prompt before starting for faster run time:

# jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10

#Importing and installing necessary packages
!pip install lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint;

base_url = 'https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/'

ending = ['american-airlines', 'delta-air-lines', 'united-airlines',
           'southwest-airlines', 'alaska-airlines']

for ending in endings:
    url = base_url + ending
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find('div', id='container')

# Retrieving all reviews
titles = results.find_all('h2', class_='text_header')

for title in titles:
    print(title, end="\n"*2)
```

My output:

```
<h2 class="text_header">"first class customer service"</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">"deeply unsatisfactory"</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">"Everything was just fabulous"</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">"Messed up airline"</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">"agents who obviously care so much" </h2>

<h2 class="text_header">“communication was sorely lacking”</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">"Never encountered ruder gate workers"</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">"Our check-in bag was badly damaged"</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">"never book again with Alaska Airlines"</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">"I could not get on the plane"</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">The Worlds Best Airlines</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">THE NICEST AIRPORT STAFF</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">THE CLEANEST AIRLINE</h2>

<h2 class="text_header">Alaska Airlines Photos</h2>
```

I expected to get this output but for all 5 URLs. How can I retrieve the review titles from all URLs?

Comment: On each iteration of the first for-loop, `results` is overwritten. You can e.g. put everything that runs after the first for-loop in this for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your results in each loop - Store results in a `list` to iterate these in another `for-loop` or scrape needed information directly - Be aware that you just get the reviews from the first review page per airline, to get all of them you have to implement another `loop` to iterate all pages per airline (get an idea of it after reviewing the examples).

Example is focused on first page as descriped in your OP and stores results in a list of dict, that you could simply convert into dataframe:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

base_url = 'https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/'

endings = ['american-airlines', 'delta-air-lines', 'united-airlines',
           'southwest-airlines', 'alaska-airlines']

results = []
data = []

for ending in endings:
    url = base_url + ending
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    for e in soup.select('article[itemprop="review"]'):
        data.append({
            'title': e.h2.text,
            'airline': ending,
            'rating':e.select_one('span[itemprop="ratingValue"]').text
        })
```

`data` will look like:

```
[{'title': '"nothing but a headache"',
  'airline': 'american-airlines',
  'rating': '1'},
 {'title': '“provide vegan options”',
  'airline': 'american-airlines',
  'rating': '2'},
 {'title': '“created so much stress and hassle”',
  'airline': 'american-airlines',
  'rating': '1'},...]
```

Transform `data` into dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

|  | title | airline | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "nothing but a headache" | american-airlines | 1 |
| 1 | “provide vegan options” | american-airlines | 2 |
| 2 | “created so much stress and hassle” | american-airlines | 1 |
| 3 | "Terrible from start to finish" | american-airlines | 1 |
| 4 | "my bags are stuck in Charlotte" | american-airlines | 1 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 45 | “communication was sorely lacking” | alaska-airlines | 1 |
| 46 | "Never encountered ruder gate workers" | alaska-airlines | 3 |
| 47 | "Our check-in bag was badly damaged" | alaska-airlines | 1 |
| 48 | "never book again with Alaska Airlines" | alaska-airlines | 4 |
| 49 | "I could not get on the plane" | alaska-airlines | 1 |

---

###### How to get "all results"

To give you an idea how to work on with all results, check what the additional `while-loop` is doing - Keep in mind to be gentle with websites you scrape and also some delay:

```
for ending in endings:
    url = f'https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/{ending}/page/1/?sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100'
    while True:
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        for e in soup.select('article[itemprop="review"]'):
            data.append({
                'title': e.h2.text,
                'airline': ending,
                'rating':e.select_one('span[itemprop="ratingValue"]').text
            })
        if soup.select_one('article.comp_reviews-pagination ul li:last-of-type a'):
            url = base_url + soup.select_one('article.comp_reviews-pagination ul li:last-of-type a').get('href')
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you so much for resolving this issue! I spent days trying to fix this on my own and now I finally know the root cause of the problem. Your solution provided more help than what was asked and made my data cleaner to look at. Thanks again!